# Example of a nontrivial ring homomorphism from $M_{2}(R)$ to any commutative ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

Can someone give me an example of a homomorphism from $M_{2}(R)$ (with $R$ an arbitrary ring) to a **nontrivial** commutative ring?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Such a homomorphism would have a kernel that necessarily contains the "commutator" ideal 
$$
\langle ab - ba : a,b \in M_2(R)\rangle.
$$ 
This ideal will consist of all trace-zero matrices. If this holds and $R$ does not have characteristic $2$, then it would follow that the homomorphism must be the map $a \mapsto \frac 12 \operatorname{tr}(a)$, which is never a homomorphism

Comment: For the case of characteristic $2$, we find that the commutator ideal is equal to all of  $M_2(R)$, which again rules out the existence of a non-trivial homomorphism with this kernel.